# Resharper not allowing me to refactor a static method to an instance method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, refactoring, resharper, resharper-7.1

I'm using ReSharper to refactor a static method to an instance method, but ReSharper is throwing an error that says:

> method has no suitable parameter that can be made into 'this'

What does this mean? Here is my class method:

```
public static DateTime PreviousOrCurrentQuarterEnd(DateTime date)
{
    Quarter qrtr = GetQuarter(date);
    DateTime endOfQuarter = GetEndOfQuarter(date.Year, qrtr);
    if (endOfQuarter == date)
        return date;
    else
    {
        DateTime startOfLast = GetStartOfQuarter(date.Year, qrtr);
        return startOfLast.AddDays(-1);
    }
}
```

Both `GetEndOfQuarter` and `GetStartOfQuarter` are other static methods inside the same class.

Comment: Please post all of your code for this class.

Comment: No, it says nothing about line numer or anything. Its a pop up message box that is all it says. No no parameters in constructor, constructors don't have parameters in constructor because there is no constructor.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to do anything special to make this an instance method. Just remove the static qualifier and be done.

Resharper has that functionality to turn the following static method into an instance method:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void DoSomething( MyClass thing, int value) {
        thing.Action (value) ;
   } 
}
```

Becomes

```
public class MyClass {
    public void DoSomething( int value) {
        this.Action (value) ;
   } 
}
```

Notice the change from 'thing'  to 'this'.

Comment: well, I could do that but there are like 20+ methods in the class that are all static. I thought there was a way Resharper could refactor the whole class to make it an instance class?

Comment: @user1186050 Are you sure you want to do that? If a method _can_ be static, it usually should be. You should think carefully before introducing state like this.

Comment: If you check out [Make Methods Non-Static](https://buildbroke.com/refactoring/resharper/2015/04/15/make-methods-non-static.html) it has step by step directions how to do this. After you do it once or twice it doesn't take as long as you might think is totally worth it if the static class is used in more than five or so places.